# GPU Image : Best resolution with Higher FPS

Tags: ios, iphone, gpuimage, ipod-touch, gpuimagestillcamera

I am using GPU framework, to record videos.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) GPUImageStillCamera *stillCamera;
```

I am setting this property which changes **Resolution** and **FPS**.

```
self.stillCamera.captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;
```

On iPhone6, 6+ and iPhone5s I am getting 1920*1080 with 30fps.

For **iPod5th generation** and **iPhone5**, **I need 24fps** with 1920*1080 resolution, same as Native camera app.
But I am Only getting 8-9FPS with 1920*1080 resolution.

I have tried value AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 as well.

I have also tried,

```
[self.stillCamera.inputCamera lockForConfiguration:nil];

self.stillCamera.inputCamera.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 24);
self.stillCamera.inputCamera.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 24);
[self.stillCamera.inputCamera unlockForConfiguration];
```

but this not affecting when I am using `self.stillCamera.captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;`

I have also tried,

```
[self.stillCamera setFrameRate:24];
```

this is also not working with `self.stillCamera.captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;`

I have also tried this function `[self configureCameraForHighestFrameRate:self.stillCamera.inputCamera];`as well, from apple documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/index.html
but I am only getting FPS near 18, with 1280*720 resolution,

I need 1920*1080 with 24fps, on iPod5th and iPhone5.
Please help me.

You help will be appriciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't want to use a GPUImageStillCamera for video capture. You want to use a GPUImageVideoCamera for that. GPUImageStillCamera uses only the preview video feed from the still camera, which has a much lower framerate on older devices than the straight video camera.

Comment: I will try this, Thanks for timely response.

Comment: but GPUImageVideoCamera camera is super class of GPUImageStillCamera, @interface GPUImageStillCamera : GPUImageVideoCamera,

Comment: so we can access all the property of GPUImageVideoCamera by GPUImageStillCamera, so what is the issue with GPUImageStillCamera, why we can not higher FPS with GPUImageStillCamera ? I am confused at this point

Comment: Just because a subclass shares an interface does not mean it behaves the same under the hood. GPUImageStillCamera uses the still camera, GPUImageVideoCamera uses the video camera, and the two behave in a fundamentally different manner. You want to use the GPUImageVideoCamera for video.

Comment: Thanks Brad Larson, now I understand, Thanks again.